# Will we look similar to how we looked in the Dunya in Jannah?

Tags: quran, hadith, allah, jannah

In Jannah, will we look similar to how we looked in the Dunya as in similar facial features and physical traits, but perfected and beautified and free of all flaws, or will we instead get an entirely different face and body with completely different features?